# Proper Way to Load WMSLayer in ArcGIS JSAPI 4.12

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms, proxy

I'm getting `#load() Failed to load layer  TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` error when I tried to load WMSLayer in my application.

I've tried several different WMS service URLs but with no positive results. The code from the [official sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/layers-wms/index.html) doesn't work either.

A [similar question](https://community.esri.com/thread/240102-how-to-add-a-ogc-wms-layer-to-application-using-javascript-api-412) has been asked and someone suggested that using proxy might solve the issue, but implementing proxy seems to be a quite complicated process. Please note that the URL in the question has `http` instead of `https` like in my application, the error is different from what I'm getting as well.

Does anyone figure out what I'm doing wrong or anything I missed out?

Here's my code :

```
let wmsLayer = new WMSLayer({
    title: "WMS Layer",
    url: "https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service",
    sublayers: [{
        name: "OSM-WMS"
    }]
});

var basemap = new Basemap({
    baseLayers: [wmsLayer]
});

var map = new Map({
    basemap: basemap,
    layers: [gridLayer, forceSymbolLayer, measurementLayer, sketchLayer]
});

var mapView = new MapView({
    map: map,
    zoom: initZoom,
    center: initPosition
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take the code in the [official sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=layers-wms) and [change it to a MapView](https://jsbin.com/zunetahoni/1/edit?html,output), it works for me.